# Lenovo ThinkPad headphones trouble (combo jack)

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, thinkpad

Well... Sometimes ago I've bought a laptop Lenovo ThinkPad E555 with pre-installed Windows. I've removed Windows and installed Linux Mint 17.3. And now, sound through headphones does not work, only through speakers. I've tried different types of headphones: from Apple and from other producers. Combo jack does not work anyway.

In **System Settings -> Sound** I have only speakers.

My system info:

```
OS: Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
Cinnamon Version: 2.8.6
Linux Kernel: 3.19.0-32-generic
```

My **lspci | grep -i audio** looks:

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i audio
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1308
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 1309
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
Memory at f0c40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
--
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5110
Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
Memory at f0c44000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
```

PulseAudio gives me info:

```
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_01.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 5
properties:
  alsa.card = "0"
  alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
  alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf0c40000 irq 48"
  alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
  device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:01.1"
  sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/sound/card0"
  device.bus = "pci"
  device.vendor.id = "1002"
  device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
  device.product.id = "1308"
  device.form_factor = "internal"
  device.string = "0"
  device.description = "Built-in Audio"
  module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
  output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
  off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
sinks:
  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_01.1.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
sources:
  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_01.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
ports:
  hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
     properties:
        device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
  alsa.card = "1"
  alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
  alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0c44000 irq 16"
  alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
  device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
  sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1"
  device.bus = "pci"
  device.vendor.id = "1022"
  device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
  device.product.id = "780d"
  device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
  device.form_factor = "internal"
  device.string = "1"
  device.description = "Built-in Audio"
  module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
  input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
  output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
  output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
  off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog   Stereo
sources:
  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
  analog-input-microphone-internal: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
     properties:
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
  analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
     properties:
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
  analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
     properties:
        device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
```

Help me, guys! I want to listening to music in headphones :)

Comment: Are the headphones muted in `alsamixer` , and what does the output of `amixer -i -M -c 0` show ?

Comment: @cesar I've tried your command: alsamixer -i -M -c 0 and Shell said that this is wrong format. So, I've executed just alsamixer -c 0 and I've got: Card: HDA ATI HDMI; Chip: ATI R6xx HDMI; Item: S/PDIF. And I don't see headphones in alsamixer in general.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating the BIOS from HTET35WW (1.07) to HTET51WW (1.23).